# Select part of a text and create a new variable

Tags: r

I have a `DF` that has two pieces of information in a variable: name and location. I want to separate this information into two variables: `NAMES AND ID`.

My DF:

```
NAMES <- c ('Liam Smith - NY 30', 'Noah Johnson - LONDON UK-UK', 'William Williams',' James Brown - UK ',' Oliver Jones -UK YORK ',' Benjamin Garcia ',' Elijah Miller - SAN DIEGO ',' Lucas Davis - ',' Mason Rodriguez - ',' Logan Martinez - MIAMI ')
DF <-data.frame (NAMES)
```

I want to create the new variable using the “-” symbol, that is, select all content after the “-”. That way, my DF would look like this:

```
NAMES <- c ('Liam Smith - NY 30', 'Noah Johnson - LONDON UK', 'William Williams',' James Brown - UK ',' Oliver Jones -UK YORK ',' Benjamin Garcia ',' Elijah Miller - SAN DIEGO ',' Lucas Davis - ',' Mason Rodriguez - ',' Logan Martinez - MIAMI ')
ID <- c ('NY 30', '- LONDON UK-UK', 'NO_ID', 'UK', 'UK YORK', 'NO_ID', 'SAN DIEGO', '-', '-', 'MIAMI')
DF <-data.frame (NAMES, ID)
```

Note that in some situations the first character is space. That way, removing the space, my final DF would look like this:

```
NAMES <- c ('Liam Smith - NY 30', 'Noah Johnson - LONDON UK', 'William Williams',' James Brown - UK ',' Oliver Jones -UK YORK ',' Benjamin Garcia ',' Elijah Miller - SAN DIEGO ',' Lucas Davis - ',' Mason Rodriguez - ',' Logan Martinez - MIAMI ')
ID <- c ('NY 30', '- LONDON UK', 'NO_ID', 'UK', 'UK YORK', 'NO_ID', 'SAN DIEGO', '-', '-', 'MIAMI')
ID_NO_SPACE <- c ('NY 30', '- LONDON UK-UK', 'NO_ID', 'UK', 'UK YORK', 'NO_ID', 'SAN DIEGO', '-', '-', 'MIAMI')
DF <-data.frame (NAMES, ID, ID_NO_SPACE)
```

In summary, how would I go about creating a new variable from the “-“ symbol?

Comment: I think you're after [`strsplit`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strsplit)

Answer (score 0):

We can use tidyr::separate and specify the separator as "-".  After doing the separate, I remove both leading and trailing whitespace with `trimws()` and then apply the "NO_ID" value to both NA values and those that are "" (a blank cell, but not NA) using an `ifelse`.

```
DF <- DF %>%
  separate(col = NAMES, into = c("Names", 'ID'), sep = '-') %>%
  mutate(ID = trimws(ID, 'both'), # remove leading/trailing spaces
         ID = ifelse(is.na(ID)|ID=='', 'NO_ID', ID))  # apply value to NA/blanks
```

Which produces

```
               Names        ID
1        Liam Smith      NY 30
2      Noah Johnson  LONDON UK
3   William Williams     NO_ID
4       James Brown         UK
5      Oliver Jones    UK YORK
6   Benjamin Garcia      NO_ID
7     Elijah Miller  SAN DIEGO
8       Lucas Davis      NO_ID
9   Mason Rodriguez      NO_ID
10   Logan Martinez      MIAMI
```

Comment: thanks! I changed the second record and added another "-". See that your suggestion check the first "-" and separate. But I would like your suggestion to include everything that comes after the "-", so the result of the second record would be: "LONDON UK-uk". is it possible to have this change?

Comment: Yes it's possible. If you add another column to the separate `into=c("Names", "ID", "ExtraValues")`, this will end up creating another new column containing 'uk' for the second record.  You could then do a `mutate(ID= if_else(is.na(ExtraValues), ID, paste0(ID, '-', ExtraValues))`  Not super elegant, but I think that should accomplish what you're looking for